# Is this sentence complete? "Di Maria is a good player but he isn't a goalscorer, whereas Messi is"

Tags: sentence-construction

> Di Maria is a good player but he isn't a goalscorer, whereas Messi is.

Is this sentence complete or must I add the implied part at the end of the sentence? ->

> Di Maria is a good player but he isn't a goalscorer, whereas Messi is
>   a great goalscorer.

In other words, is "a great scorer" omissible in proper writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is complete as it is.

> Di Maria is a good player but he isn't a goalscorer, whereas Messi is.

is implicitly the same as

> Di Maria is a good player but he isn't a goalscorer, whereas Messi is both a good player and good at scoring goals.

It implies that both are good players but while Di Maria is not a good goalscorer (for whatever reason), Messi is a good goalscorer.

The second sentence

> Di Maria is a good player but he isn't a goalscorer, whereas Messi is a great goalscorer.

has a slightly different focus as it emphasizes that Messi is not just capable of scoring goals but by the use of *great*, that he is above average as a goalscorer.

Comment: Thank you Mick, good answer. Sadly I still struggle with omissible parts of sentences :-(.